How to resolve the "unknown array size in delete" error when using a class with a flexible array member (FAM) and a non-trivial destructor?
struct A {
  ~A () {}
};

struct S {
  S() : i(0) { }
  ~S() {}
  int i;
  
  // This fails:
  //
  // A a[];
  A a[0];
};
int main()
{
    struct A aaa;
    return 0;
}

Note that if the zero-sized array is replaced by Flexible Array Member (FAM) A a[];, an error will occur: error: unknown array size in delete.
I found this example from here.
I encountered this issue in my custom dynamically expanding container class.
My questions: how to solve it? Is a zero-sized array a valid replacement and works well?
For example, to use operator new to allocate memory for the instance of the class and use operator delete to release it like this:
size_t totalSize = sizeof(MyContainer) + capacity * sizeof(MyElement);
void* memory = operator new(totalSize);
MyContainer* container = new (memory) MyContainer();
// ...
operator delete((void*)container);


Why are you adding a zero sized array? For "resizable" arrays use std::vector (and forget about "C" style unsized arrays). Hint: In current C++ the use of naked new/delete is not recommended. (Use standard library containers, or at least std::make_unique/std::make_shared).

Zero sized arrays are an extension that isn't available in all implementations. Don't use it. std::array<A, 0> a; would be fine though

Question back : Who or what is teaching you to write "C" style code like this?

@TedLyngmo Though it's not an appropriate replacement for a flexible array member.

@HolyBlackCat No, of course. It'd only be a replacement for a zero sized array and only really useful in generic programming.

FAM are strictly old C thing, in C++ it's an extension. Some comilers treat it as size of 1 and sizeof of structure would be wrong

Flexible array members do not exist in standard C++. They may (or may not) be supported as a language extension by your specific compiler. If so, their use with other C++ features will probably be severely limited.
Replacing a flexible array member with A a[0]; does not make it better. An array can not be declared to have zero size in standard C++ either. Again, this will be some language extension of your specific compiler if it compiles. And, in contrast to proper flexible array members, they are not even standard C either, making it even less clear what the semantics are.
delete can't possibly work with a flexible array member of a type with non-trivial destructor. delete needs to know the size of the array because it would need to call the non-trivial destructor of each element of the array. But it has no way of knowing that size.
You need to allocate memory with operator new/operator new[] yourself, create objects in the memory so obtained with placement-new or std::construct_at and manually destroy each element you created with an explicit destructor call or call to std::destroy_at. Then you need to manually deallocate the memory with operator delete/operator delete[].

You are trying to apply C patterns to C++ that offer no benefit in C++.
The flexible array member is not needed to implement what you want. The user shouldn't be using a MyContainer* to refer to your container instance. Instead MyContainer should be used by-value by the user and MyContainer should be a class type holding the pointer to the dynamically allocated memory. Whether the i member is held in MyContainer or at the beginning of the allocation for the pointer it holds, is up to you.
Have a look at how standard library implementations implement std::vector. You are essentially trying to implement the same thing, with restricted feature set. std::vector is type-generic, has strong exception safety guarantees, has better algorithmic complexity than what you are trying to do, works with generic allocators instead of only new/delete, etc.
Also, these implementations do not store the size at the beginning of the allocation, but in the container object itself, but that is a minor difference. Implementing such a container in C++ correctly is non-trivial and requires decent understanding of the object model.

@PepijnKramer They are trying to implement their own std::vector-like container. I assume they have some specific reason to do so. Of course, if they just want any std::vector-like container, it is pointless to implement one yourself instead of using what is already implemented for you.

nvm already deleted my comment ;) I triggered too fast on new/delete ;)

std::vector and friends vs flexible array member is not a C++ vs C thing. There can be a legitimate need for a flexible array member or equivalent even in C++ (avoiding one extra heap allocation).

@HolyBlackCat You can always replace the flexible array member by creating individual objects in the allocated storage. That's true in C as well. The flexible array member is only a convenience, to simplify access of the objects after the header. In C++ technically it is more restrictive, because a pointer to the header can't be used to access objects after it, but passing a pointer to the underlying storage is still sufficient and it can be made type-safe in C++ by wrapping the pointer into a new type as I suggested here.

@HolyBlackCat It doesn't have to follow the usual std::vector layout and can simply be a typed pointer to the underlying storage with accessors that do pointer arithmetic + reinterpret_cast/launder into the storage to get the same convenience as flexible array members in C.

@HolyBlackCat It only becomes cumbersome if the object with flexible array following it is supposed to be shared with in one allocation with other objects. Then it would be necessary to write a pointer wrapper for each possible object combination in the storage. That's the only case where I can see a flexible array member being a better solution in terms of practicability, although presumably necessary information to access the individual objects should still be present in the program and could be incorporated into the wrapper type to make it still work.
